# Summing BigDecimals in streams API Collectors

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

My current attempt is based on double type class members:

```
public Client whoPaidTheMost() {

/*METHOD EXPLOITING STREAM API*/

return shopping.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream(),
                        Collectors.summingDouble(e->e.getKey().getPrize() * e.getValue())))) /*should be refactored*/
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue))/*should be refactored*/
        .get()
        .getKey();
}
```

shopping is basically a map: `Map<Client, Map<Product,Integer>>`,

- The outer Key represents the Client
- The inner Key represents the Product
- the inner maps value (Integer) reprents the number of specified product which belong to a specific client

**Product** class members are **name, category, price** (previously of double type) - want to refactor the provided code into one using price as a type of BigDecimal

How could I make this code work also for BigDecimals - ?

Basically I' ve refactored that arleady:

```
  Client client = shopping.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream(),
                            Collectors.mapping(e -> BigDecimal.valueOf(new Long(e.getValue())).multiply(e.getKey().getPrize()),
                                    Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)))))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max((e1, e2) -> (e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue())))
            .get()
            .getKey();
```

Still wondering if it's possible to refactor this without using:  `Collectors.mapping(e -> BigDecimal.valueOf(new Long(e.getValue())).multiply(e.getKey().getPrize())` before `Collectors.reducing` ?

Comment: As the method name suggests, returned Client is a Client that paid the most

Comment: very beautiful, and then, who will maintain this monster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor it like this,

```
shopping.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.flatMapping(
                e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                    .map(innerEntry -> innerEntry.getKey().getPrice()
                    .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(innerEntry.getValue()))),
            Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get().getKey();
```

You don't need any additional `mapping` `Collector` here. Merely use the `map` operator to convert your `Map.Entry` into a `BigDecimal` based on your computation, and pass that `Stream<BigDecimal>` down. The final reduction operator does the trick here. Zero acts as a good identity element for this sum.

Comment: Yea, that's another way to do it, anyway is it possible to map the values inside Collectors.reducing?

Comment: No it is not possible since it takes a `BinaryOperator`

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a `Collector` that sums `BigDecimal`s, this should work:

```
Collector<BigDecimal, ?, BigDecimal> collector 
    = Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: That's what I've tried. Not sure, how to use it in that case

Comment: There is a similar overload which takes three arguments; the one that goes in between the other two converts your `Map` to a `BigDecimal`.  More details on the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-U-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

Comment: This gives me "no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that MyEntity conforms to BigDecimal"